# Update Datetime field from date and time columns in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to update a field with date and time fields. but it does not add the time value into it. I can see only date value being added.

Tried using below statement

```
set TransDateTime =cdate('#' + cstr(Transaction_Date) + ' '  + cstr(transaction_time) + '#'
```

or

```
set TransDateTime =cdate(Transaction_Date) + ' '  + cstr(transaction_time)
```

I added the column with datetime but the values are only dates.

Ended up using a numeric type using below query

```
alter table table1 add TransDateTime numeric(14,0) 

update table1 set TransDateTime =ccur(year(transaction_date) & format(month(transaction_date),'00') & format(day(transaction_date) ,'00') 
                        & format(hour(transaction_time),'00') & format(minute(Transaction_time),'00') & format(second(transaction_time),'00'))
```

Which served the purpose

Comment: It doesn't serve the purpose. Date/time should always be handled as date/time, not strings, not numbers. No exceptions. Your formula is a confusing mix-up.

Comment: Data type _Currency_ is for money, not dates. If you wish a plain read-out, you can use _Format_ for a string: `Format([DateField], "yyyymmddhhnnss")` or _Val_ and _Format_ for a number: `Val(Format([DateField], "yyyymmddhhnnss"))`

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler:

```
Set TransDateTime = Transaction_Date + Transaction_Time
```

Comment: Datatype mismatch. Tried setting TransDateTime to both date as well as time.

Comment: set TransDateTime =cstr(TRANSACTION_DATE)+' ' + cstr(TRANSACTION_TIME)    . Using this one without error . but only date is entered

Comment: A Date _plus_ Time cannot create a data type mismatch, except - of course - if your date field is not of data type Date. Even if either Date or Time is Null, the result will be Null which is accepted by a field of data type Date using the default settings.